What shoud I do about zsys in ubuntu 24.04
I have been upgrading Ubuntu with zfs for many years.
Now I am using version 24.04. If I had a fresh install I would not have zsys. I would like my system to be as close as possible to the release version. I do not want left over software that may not be supported.
I think that I need to remove it. What is the proper way of doing it without affecting the boot system.

Did you ever figure this out? I did some looking online and all I could find was the following reddit post and github gist. https://old.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/um7h6i/zfs_on_root_with_2204_without_zsys/ and the gist https://gist.github.com/kimono-koans/7641ee7bc7ce91f520b324bb08d699c8 I'm not sure what the github gist is actually telling one to do though.
